# Maximise area of rectangle with fixed perimeter

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits

I've got a problem where a rectangle's area must be maximised given a fixed perimeter of $60$m.

Assuming a length of $x$ and height of $y$ I wrote an equation $y = 30x - x^2$ which i differentiated, set to zero and found the critical value of $15$m per side.

However this is a square not a rectangle as the question requests.

I think the answer would be the limit of $y$ as $x \to 15$ and just wanted to double check with you guys if you agree or if you have a different answer.

Cheers lads

Comment: The term *rectangle* is usually defined to include squares.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle) for example.  However, if the question is truly asking about oblong rectangles, then the answer is that there is no maximum, only an unattainable supremum $225\,\mathrm{m}^2$.

Comment: Cheers L.F. I didn't realise rectangles included squares. Massive help.

Comment: A square is just a special case of a rectangle more specifically a square is rectangle with all equal sides.

Answer (score 3):

A rectangle has $4$ right angles, so a square is a special type of rectangle that also has $4$ congruent sides (i.e. a square is both a rhombus and a rectangle).  A square will always have the maximum area for a given perimeter when working with rectangles.